# Creating a Search and Highlighting Found Item

Tags: vb.net-2010

I am able to create a search but I have no idea how to get the item I searched for to be highlighted in my list... here is what I have:

```
 Dim foundItem As ListViewItem = ListView1.FindItemWithText(Me.searchText.Text, False,    
 0, True)

    If (foundItem IsNot Nothing) Then
        ListView1.TopItem = foundItem
        foundItem.Selected() = True
    End If
```

I am just not too sure how to get it to highlight so I can prove that it has been found... please help!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using foundItem.Selected, should you try changing the item background color? I am just wondering if more than one items are found and you haven't set multiselect = true in your list, then it may not be able to select all items.